# Windows Bash and webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser

Tags: python, browser, jupyter-notebook, python-webbrowser

I am using Windows Bash. I was trying to run `jupyter notebook` command. It doesn't open browser for me. But It shows me:

```
[I 16:19:44.425 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/Dida
[I 16:19:44.425 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 16:19:44.427 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=056d3c3335bef80c2ae4a2e9c70bc8a62ea7c2bd0f1cc075
[I 16:19:44.431 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 16:19:44.433 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 16:19:44.433 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=056d3c3335bef80c2ae4a2e9c70bc8a62ea7c2bd0f1cc075
```

Well, I don't have any problem to copy/paste `http://localhost:8888/?token=...`. Everything is fine. I can work with Jupyter. But in my dreams I want jupyter to open browser by itself (without copy/paste each time).

So, I tried to run  `jupyter notebook --browser=chrome` and to play with this parameter value. I tried to type full path to `chrome.exe`. But I am unlucky.

After that I got disappointed and go to `python` and in order to show browsers which Windows Bash knows I did

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> print(webbrowser._browsers)
{}
```

Well, nothing! After that. I was trying to play with `webbrowser` library. `register, open, get`-commands. I am always getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/webbrowser.py", line 51, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

But I feel like I am helpless. Help!